# Reading and Writing to ChannelBuffer is not working properly

Tags: java, netty, httpresponse

I want to read the binary data stored in the `ChannelBuffer` object contained in an `HttpResponse`. I have tried with the below code to read and save from the `ChannelBuffer`, but it is not working. What is the correct way of reading the binary data stored in the channel buffer?

```
ChannelBuffer chanBuff = response.getContent();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);       
outputStream.write(chanBuff.array());                   
outputStream.close();
```

The above code throws an exception from `chanBuff.array()` (`UnsupportedOperationException`). Not sure what is the correct way of copying byte array from `ChannelBuffer`.

The purpose of storing this content (e.g. media) is to save and transcode it. However I am consistently getting the saved file size as zero.

I also intend to copy the processed data back into the HTTP Response via `ChannelBuffer`. For writing back into HTTP Message, I have the below code. This code sometimes throws `ArrayOutOfBoundException`. What is the correct approach here?

```
ChannelBuffer dynamicBuffer = dynamicBuffer();
dynamicBuffer.clear();
dynamicBuffer.ensureWritableBytes(fileLen);

ChannelBufferOutputStream buffOutStream = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(dynamicBuffer);

byte[] byteBuf = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
int offSet = 0;

while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(byteBuf)) != -1) {
    buffOutStream.write(byteBuf, offSet, bytesRead);
    offSet += bytesRead;
}

response.setContent(EMPTY_BUFFER);
response.setContent(buffOutStream.buffer());
response.setHeader("Content-Type", contType);
response.setHeader("Content-Length", fileLen);
```

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you should not keep increasing the offset. That's an offset into the buffer, not the file. You should use zero for the offset throughout.